# Which alternative is that instance of a ADT?

Tags: rascal

I have defined an AlgebraicDataType and an instance of it:

```
data Expr = const(int n)
          | var(str name)
          | add(Expr lhs, Expr rhs)
          | mult(Expr lhs, Expr rhs)
          ;
```

I need a boolean indicating if a given instance of it is of *type* `add`:

```
isAdd(add(var("x"), const(3)));  // true
isAdd(var("x"));                 // false
isAdd(const(3));                 // false
isAdd(mult(var("x"), const(3))); //false
```

Maybe it exists a built-in function or operator, which would be a more generic solution than :

```
bool isAdd(add(Expr lhs, Expr rhs)) = true;
bool isAdd(Expr e) = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in operator `is` indeed: `isAdd(expr) = expr is add`.

Comment: So logical. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Next to Rodin's answer there are cases where the `is` operator can not distinguish between overloaded operators. In this case a handwritten predicate does help, but using a default modifier to catch the false cases:

Say we also have a ternary add, `data Expr = add(Expr, Expr, Expr) then this will only give true for the binary alternative;

```
 bool isAdd(add(_, _)) = true;
 default bool isAdd(Expr _) = false;
```

Or if you wish to inline the match predicate then the `:=` operator is also a Boolean expression:

```
 if(add(_, _) := myExpr) ...
```